# Connecting and retrieving data from to Bing API using Python

Tags: python-3.x, bing-api

I am trying to connect to the following URL https://searchapi.pubcenter.microsoft.com/api/v1/reportJobs/ using Python from web based application. I have completed the authorisation process and have all the necessary credential details to login (UserID, Password, Access Token, Refresh Token etc.)

Any idea how I can connect to the API and retrieve data from there using the refresh token?

I was trying something like the below:
credential_details = {"RefreshToken":refresh_token,"ClientId":client_id,"ClientSecret":client_secret,"DeveloperToken":developer_token} and sending a session.get request to the corresponding URL, but getting the following error:

*"errors":[{"code":"AuthorizationFailure","description":"Invalid credentials provided.  Please verify your log-in information, and then try again."}]*